# Laravel Pass Data To Form on Another Page

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to essentially pass a variable from one page url to another to assist in filling out a form.

I have a `Script` model and a `Prescription` model. Each script can have multiple prescriptions. So on the Scripts show page, I'm wanting to have a create button that allows users to click it, and it sends them to the Prescriptions create page, but auto-fills out the `script_id` for the user in the controller. This way it is definitively tagged to the correct script.

So if someone clicks on 'Create Prescription' on `test.com/scripts/34/show`, it takes them to `test.com/prescriptions/create` and automatically applies `34` as the `script_id` field - ideally either a hidden field, or directly passed to the controller somehow so that the user can't tamper with it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you please show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session, before returning prescriptions/create page you can do

```
Session::flash('script_id', $script_id);
```

and when user submits prescription creation just take it

```
$script_id = Session::get('script_id');
```

Comment: If you use Flash method, it will be removed from session when you get it, so you won't have to remove manually